# Drop order for when boxed struct contains reference

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, trait-objects

I'm trying to make a node structure but I have no idea why this won't compile ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da7ecbd971e756d40a51b7f69bb70d14)):

```rust
trait SomeTrait {}

struct SomeObject<'a> {
    something: &'a dyn SomeTrait,
}
impl<'a> SomeTrait for SomeObject<'a> {}

struct OtherObject {}
impl SomeTrait for OtherObject {}

pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>,
}
fn main() {
    let a = vec![OtherObject {}];

    let b: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = a
        .iter()
        .map(|d| Box::new(SomeObject { something: d }) as Box<dyn SomeTrait>)
        .collect();

    //But if i comment this it's fine... why?
    Box::new(Node { children: b });
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:38
   |
17 |     let b: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = a
   |                                      ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |         .iter()
19 |         .map(|d| Box::new(SomeObject { something: d }) as Box<dyn SomeTrait>)
   |                  ----------------------------------------------------------- returning this value requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`
...
24 | }
   | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why does it say that `a` is still in use? Shouldn't the other variables be dropped before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed version:

```rust
trait SomeTrait {}

struct SomeObject<'a> {
    something: &'a dyn SomeTrait,
}
impl<'a> SomeTrait for SomeObject<'a> {}

struct OtherObject {}
impl SomeTrait for OtherObject {}

pub struct Node<'a> {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'a>>,
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![OtherObject {}];

    let b: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = a
        .iter()
        .map(|d| Box::new(SomeObject { something: d }) as Box<dyn SomeTrait>)
        .collect();

    Box::new(Node { children: b });
}
```

So, what's the problem ?

```
pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>,
}
```

is the same as

```
pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'static>>,
}
```

which means ([1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds),[2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound)) that the `SomeTriat` objects must not hold any references that are not `'static`. But you have:

```
.map(|d| Box::new(SomeObject { something: d }) as Box<dyn SomeTrait>)
```

where `|d|` is actually a reference that does not live for as long as `'static` (it is valid for as long as the vector `a` is in scope, which is less than `'static`), therefore the error message:

```
returning this value requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`
```

By making your `Node` object generic over the lifetime parameter `'a`, you can lift that restriction. After that change, your `Node<'a>` objects will be bounded by the lifetime of `.map(|d|...)` reference

##### **Resources**:

- [lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds)
- [`'static` as trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound)
- [drop order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html)
- [more on drop order](https://vojtechkral.github.io/blag/rust-drop-order/)

Answer (score 3):

The type of `Node`:

```
pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>,
}
```

does not capture any lifetime information, even though the specific implementation of `SomeTrait`, ie `SomeObject`, carries references. The borrow checker then must infer this lifetime to be `'static`, as if you had written:

```
pub struct Node {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'static>>,
}
```

You can fix this by expressing that `Node` *might* contain non-static references:

```
pub struct Node<'a> {
    children: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'a>>,
}
```

This allows the borrow checker to track the borrow correctly.